# How to use if else statement to check that table has this value

Tags: laravel

**This is my member's `light` table**

0 mean no light, 1 mean light on

```
|id| sx_ID | gylight| 
---------------------
|1 |SX00001|    0   |
|2 |SX00002|    1   |
|3 |SX00003|    1   | 
---------------------
```

**This is my `guanyin` table**

```
|id| sx_ID | gylight_number| 
----------------------------
|1 |SX00002|    A1-1       |
|2 |SX00002|    A1-17      |
|3 |SX00003|    A78        | 
----------------------------
```

**It have the data in the table, but it still display the msg 'No data'**

[image]

**This is my `view.blade.php`**

```
<thead>
    <th></th>

    <th>Receipt</th>

    <th>Amount</th>

    <th>Number</th>

    <th>Label</th>

    <th>Remark</th>

    <th>Start Date</th>

    <th>Due Date</th>

    <th>CreatedBy</th>

    <th>UpdatedBy</th>
</thead>

<tbody id="gyFee">
    @forelse ($gylight as $item)
    @if($item->sx_ID == $light->sx_ID )
    <tr id="gyPost_{{$item->id}}">
      <td id="btncz">
        @if($permission->role_id == 1)
        <a href="#"
        data-id="{{$item->id}}"
        data-gylight_receipt="{{$item->gylight_receipt}}"
        data-gylight_amount="{{$item->gylight_amount}}"
        data-gylight_number="{{$item->gylight_number}}"
        data-gylight_label="{{$item->gylight_label}}"
        data-gylight_remark="{{$item->gylight_remark}}"
        data-gylight_sdate_string="{{$item->gylight_sdate_string}}"
        data-gylight_edate_string="{{$item->gylight_edate_string}}"
        class="btn btn-success gyEdit"
        data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
        @else 
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a>
        @endif
      </td>
      <td id="receipt">{{ $item->gylight_receipt }}</td>
      <td id="amount">RM{{ $item->gylight_amount }}</td>
      <td id="number">{{ $item->gylight_number }}</td>
      <td id="label">{{ $item->gylight_label }}</td>
      <td id="remark">{{ $item->gylight_remark }}</td>
      <td id="sdate">{{ $item->gylight_sdate_string }}</td>
      <td id="edate">{{ $item->gylight_edate_string }}</td>
      <td id="created">{{ $item->created_by }}</td>
      <td id="updated">{{ $item->updated_by }}</td>
    </tr>
    @endif
    
    @empty
    
    @endforelse 
</tbody>
<tfoot>     
    <tr>
      @if($light->sx_ID == $gylight->first()->sx_ID)
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#guanyinModal">Add</button></td>
      <td style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle" colspan="7"> 
      </td>
      @else
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#guanyinModal">Add</button></td>
      <td id="lastgy" style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle" colspan="7">
      No data 
      </td>
      @endif
    </tr>
    
</tfoot>
```

**This is my view `controller`**

```
    public function view(Light $light){

    $gylight = Guanyin::latest()->first()->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $permission = Auth::user();

    return view('admin.light.view',[
        'light' => $light,
        'gylight' => $gylight,
        'permission' =>$permission,
    ]);
}
```

Comment: as per your this condition `@if($light->sx_ID == $gylight->first()->sx_ID)` it is working fine, can you specify in detail what is happening now, what is the desired result

Comment: @bhucho The msg No data should be hidden when there is data. The msg No data should be come out when `@if($light->sx_ID != $gylight->sx_ID)` . Actually I want to do the code is `@if($light->sx_ID == $gylight->sx_ID)` but it didn't work

Comment: what `$gylight->first()->sx_ID` is doing is from the `$gylight` the first() selects the first value, then `->sx_ID` gives you the sx_ID, it is not matching with the sx_ID of $light thus moving to else statement, you need to change some things then it will work I am posting it in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your controller,

```
$gylight = Guanyin::latest()->first();
```

this will return the latest w.r.t created_at column, & first will fetch only one value. you need not use `->orderBy('id','desc')->get();` again.
If you want to get orderby descending to id, you can use other variable for that say,

```
$gylightOrderById = Guanyin::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

& use it separately.

---

So, for your `@forelse ($gylight as $item)` would be changed to `@forelse ($gylightOrderById as $item)`

&
you can use `@if($light->sx_ID == $gylight->sx_ID)` for later comparison.